# How is Stage related to Gazebo

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

How is Stage related to Gazebo strategically. Is there any integration between Stage and gazebo such plugin integration for simulation of controllers and sensors.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/97181/how-is-stage-related-to-gazebo/) by [rnunziata](https://answers.ros.org/users/5119/rnunziata/) on ROS Answers with karma: 713 on 2013-11-02

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Hansg91](https://answers.ros.org/users/1621/hansg91/) on 2013-11-02**:
I'm not very familiar with gazebo's uses, but I believe they are both simulators, one more advanced than the other. I doubt there is any integration between the two.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

They are completely independent. No code is shared between both.
Stage is much simpler, only for 2D objects, without physics.

---

Originally posted by [KruseT](https://answers.ros.org/users/888/kruset/) with karma: 7848 on 2013-11-03

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1